# Retrieving array from another class to use in dialogue box

Tags: android, arrays, azure-sql-database

I have a java class which connects to my cloud database and adds all the items into an array. Now i have a seperate java class where i would like to use the same array to get the position in order to create a dialouge which the user clicks in order to get more information on the item.

here is my `getData.java`:

```
public class GetData {
Connection connect;
String ConnectionResult = "";
Boolean isSuccess = false;


public List<Map<String,String>> doInBackground() {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    try
    {
        ConnectionHelper conStr=new ConnectionHelper();
        connect =conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
        if (connect == null)
        {
            ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Change below query according to your own database.
            String query = "select * from cc_rail";
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()){
                Map<String,String> datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                datanum.put("NAME",rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                datanum.put("PRICE",rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                datanum.put("RANGE",rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                datanum.put("SUPPLIER",rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                datanum.put("SIZE",rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }
```

and in my `mainactivity.java` where i would like to use this array i have the following code:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    private ImageView icon;
    private String fullName,partyName;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        /** To change selected state view */
        view.setSelected(true);
        String Slecteditem = datanum.get(position);
```

How do i get the array from my `getdata.java`

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: How do i get the array from my `getdata.java`

Comment: Would you have multiple instances of `GetData` at any point? Or can a single object be used multiple times throughout the app?

Comment: single object being used multiple times

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description. we can use [android.app.Application] to store the array. [android.app.Application] is the global class and it exists throughout the entire application life cycle.

Here is a demo for your reference:

We can create a class extends [android.app.Application]:

```
package cn.azurepro.test.global;

import android.app.Application;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;


    public void setArrayList(List<Map<String, String>> data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MobileServiceClient getMobileServiceClient(){
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

}
```

Then set the full name of this class as the name attribute of Application as below:

[image]

Then we can get it in different activities as below:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyApplication myApplication= (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
        List<Map<String, String>> data = myApplication.getMobileServiceClient();
```

We can set the `List<Map<String, String>>` as below:

```
Context.getApplication().setArrayList(data);
```